# keras custom metric function how to feed 2 model outputs to a single metric evaluation function

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I have an CNN object detection model which has two heads(outputs) with tensor names `'classification'` and `'regression'`.

I want to define a metric function that **accepts both the outputs at the same time**, so that it looks into the **regression predictions** to decide which indexes to retain and use those indexes to select tensors from **classification predictions** and calculate some metric.

my current metric function defined with help from [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation#passing_data_to_multi-input_multi-output_models):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import MeanMetricWrapper

class Accuracy2(MeanMetricWrapper):

    def __init__(self, name='dummyAccuracy', dtype=None):
        super(Accuracy2, self).__init__(metric_calculator_func, name, dtype=dtype)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='lol', initializer='zeros')

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        if 'fn' in config:
          config.pop('fn')
        return super(Accuracy2, cls).from_config(config)


    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
      print("==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===")
      print("Y-True {}".format(y_true))
      print("Y-Pred {}".format(y_pred))
      print("==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===")

      update_ops = [self.true_positives.assign_add(1.0)]
      return tf.group(update_ops)

    def result(self):
      return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
      # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
      self.true_positives.assign(0.)
```

which I call the during model compilation as :

```
training_model.compile(
    loss={
        'regression'    : regression_loss(),
        'classification': classification_loss()
    },
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, clipnorm=0.001),
    metrics=[Accuracy2()]
)
```

screen log during **tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate** is:

> INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0075738616, step = 31 (11.941 sec)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 4.51218
>
> INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.01015341, step = 36 (1.108 sec)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 40 into /tmp/tmpcla2n3gy/model.ckpt.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>   Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(?, 120087, 5), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
>   Tensor("regression/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 4), dtype=float32)
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>   Tensor("IteratorGetNext:2", shape=(?, 120087, 2), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
>   Tensor("classification/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32)
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-06-24T08:20:35Z
>   INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457345: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457398: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457419: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457425: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457539: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9855 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/tmpcla2n3gy/model.ckpt-40
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [10/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [20/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [30/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [40/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [50/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [60/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [70/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [80/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [90/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [100/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-06-24-08:20:44
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 40: _focal = 0.0016880237, _smooth_l1 = 0.0, dummyAccuracy = 100.0, global_step = 40, loss = 0.0016880237

This line :

```
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(?, 120087, 5), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
Tensor("regression/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 4), dtype=float32)
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:2", shape=(?, 120087, 2), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
Tensor("classification/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32)
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
```

shows that `Accuracy2()` is invoked two times first for **regression** then for **classification**.
but I want that it gets invoked once with **regression** and **classification** fed into it together

Answer (score 2):

I have found suggestion to implement metrics through callback.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4506

Maybe it helps you and those with similar problem to figure out the needed solution

Comment: Cool ! looks helpful